# How to change categorical (consists both alphabet and numbers) into numerical using map in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning

I have a column X in my dataset which consists following data

```
1,
2,
4,
5more,
3,
2
```

So when I used

```
dataset['X'].map({
"5more" : 5
})
```

It is converting all values to `NaN`.
How to convert these dataset to numerical without NaN/Infinity?

Answer (score 0):

With map all keys that are not in dictionary are replaced with NaN. From [pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) on `map`

> When arg is a dictionary, values in Series that are not in the dictionary (as keys) are converted to NaN.

You can try using `replace`:

```
dataset['X'].replace("5more" : 5})
```

You can also add `inplace=True` to replace inplace:

```
dataset['X'].replace("5more" : 5}, inplace=True)
```